# Multiple dictionaries causing AttributeError?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, attributeerror

I have 1 variable that contains multiple dictionaries:

```
a = {"foo": "foo"}, {"foo2": "foo2"}
```

But if I do:

```
a.get("foo")
```

it returns as `AttributeError`:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: `a` is a tuple in your case as it holds more than 1 value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple dictionaries does not exist in Python.
If you define `a` as:

```
a = {"foo": "foo"}, {"foo2": "foo2"}
```

`a` will be a `tuple`. So you have to call the element as follow:

```
a[0].get("foo")
```

To use `a.get` method you have to define `a` as follow:

```
a = {"foo": "foo", "foo2": "foo2"}
```

Now `a.get("foo")` call will have as output `"foo"`.

Comment: Ok so i have to merge the dicts right? But if i have:

`a = {"foo", "a"},{"foo", "a2"}`

?

Comment: dictionaries can have more than 1 key. You can define multiple keys as I did with the second definition of `a`.

Comment: `a = {"foo", "a"},{"foo", "a2"}` is a tuple. so you can call the element as follow `a[0].get("foo")`

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning to variable a tuple of two elements which are dicts.

This:

```
a = {"foo": "foo"}, {"foo2": "foo2"}
```

is equivalent to:

```
a = ({"foo": "foo"}, {"foo2": "foo2"})
```

so you cannot access to dictionary in this way you try.

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
```

tells you that you want to use `get` attribute on tuple, but tuple hasn't it.

**Solving issue**:

You can assign to `a` variable for example one dict:

```
a = {"foo": "foo", "foo2": "foo2"}
```

and in this case you can use:

```
a.get("foo")
```

which will print

```
foo
```